# Greater than OR equal (based on boolean condition)

Tags: javascript, typescript, logical-operators

What is a simple construction for a greater than OR equal where the equal part is only applied based on a boolean parameter.

A straightforward way (Type(Java)Script):

```
function isGreaterThanOrEqual(a: number, b:number, allowEqual: boolean = false): boolean {
  if(allowEqual){
    return a >= b;
  } else {
    return a > b
  }
}
```

I have a (rotated) rectangle collision detection method in which numerous of these comparisons are made. Sometimes I want to include rectangles touching each other and sometimes not (they must "really" overlap) that's why this optional `allowEqual` parameter comes in handy.

I would like to prevent to have this if statement at numerous places in this method and prefer an elegant one-liner.

Can this be done in a one-liner in any way?

Comment: `return (allowEqual && a >= b) || a > b` would work too.

Comment: @Federico even return (allowEqual && a == b) || a > b would work

Comment: @tehvan sure, but I think the intent is more clear if written like I did :)

Comment: If you want elegancy, just rename the function to isGreater. If at a later stage you want to take a different approach, you only have one place to change in stead of many.

Comment: @tehvan nice suggestion, let me add: function named "IsGreaterThan" and the parameter called "orEqual".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a staged approach by returning either the value of the greater check or check `allowEqual` and the identity check.

```
return a > b || allowEqual && a === b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (a - b) >= (+(!allowEqual)) * Number.EPSILON;
```

Explained:

If `allowEqual` is `true`, its negation is coerced to `0`, so `a - b` has to be at least `0`. If `allowEqual` is false, its negation is coerced to `1`, so `a - b` has to be at least the smallest possible distance between two numbers.

Comment: Clever, but if I found something like this in a codebase I would start looking for you and everyone you love :P

Comment: Honestly, so would I. This is exactly the kind of thing I call being clever for cleverness' sake; I posted this as more of a curiosity than a practical solution.

Comment: @Federico +1 for that